# Keypresses not registering on my js tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, keyboard, tampermonkey

I coded a little thing to make my life easier in which upon clicking the key space, it would rapidly click number pad 3 and then left click. However, it doesn't seem to register either.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
        if (event.code === "Space") {
            // Space key pressed
            var pressKey3 = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { 'keyCode': 51, 'which': 51 });
            document.dispatchEvent(pressKey3);

            // Simulate left-click
            var leftClick = new MouseEvent('click', { 'button': 0 });
            document.dispatchEvent(leftClick);
        }
    })
})();
```

I know the alert and password work so its on the right site. I tried making space make an alert happen, which worked so I know that it is an issue with either the num pad 3 or left click.